# JavaScript Comparator Function for Sorting Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, sorting

I am attempting to get the following JavaScript comparator function for an array which contains objects (keyed) but the below code isn't working.

I have tried many examples online (changing them per my needs) but so far no good.

See below for the code. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your time.

(As an FYI, the teContainer object below get's filled via an AJAX call)

```
var teContainer = {};
for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
    var key = result.d[i].PersonId;
    teContainer[key] = {
        displayText: result.d[i].DLSPersonId + ' ' + result.d[i].PersonLastName + ', ' + result.d[i].PersonFirstName.substring(0, 5),
        tEFirstName: result.d[i].PersonFirstName,
        tELastName: result.d[i].PersonLastName,
        tEID: result.d[i].PersonId,
        orgID: result.d[i].DLS_OrgId
    };
}
function tECompare(a, b) {
    if (a.tELastName < b.tELastName)
        return -1;
    if (a.tELastName > b.tELastName)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
teContainer.sort(tECompare);
```

**Edit**: Thanks to the answer; here is the corrected code which works:

```
var teContainer = [];
for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
    teContainer.push = ({
        displayText: result.d[i].DLSPersonId + ' ' + result.d[i].PersonLastName + ', ' + result.d[i].PersonFirstName.substring(0, 5),
        tEFirstName: result.d[i].PersonFirstName,
        tELastName: result.d[i].PersonLastName,
        tEID: result.d[i].PersonId,
        orgID: result.d[i].DLS_OrgId
    });
}
function tECompare(a, b) {
    if (a.tELastName < b.tELastName)
        return -1;
    if (a.tELastName > b.tELastName)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
teContainer.sort(tECompare);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not running because `sort` isn't a method of an object. `teContainer` is an object, not an array. You're probably getting the following error:

```
Calling undefined method "sort"
```

Comment: Seems like changing `var teContainer = {};` to `var teContainer = [];` would be the easy fix.

Comment: @analytalica not really. He's assigning `PersonId` as index. We don't know what those values are, or if it could affect sorting.

Comment: Thank you for such a fast answer. I'll try @analytalica's answer and see if by changing the object to an array without the PersonID key I can sort.

Answer (score 0):

In general your code is good. The main thing about sorting, is that the 'sort' function only works with Array, not with Object.

Assuming an Ajax result formatted as:

```
var result = {
  d: [
    {
      PersonId: 1,
      DLSPersonId: 1,
      PersonLastName: "Doe",
      PersonFirstName: "John",
      DLS_OrgId: 1
    },
    {
      PersonId: 2,
      DLSPersonId: 2,
      PersonLastName: "Smith",
      PersonFirstName: "Alex",
      DLS_OrgId: 2
    },
    {
      PersonId: 3,
      DLSPersonId: 3,
      PersonLastName: "Vera",
      PersonFirstName: "Luis",
      DLS_OrgId: 3
    }
  ]
};
```

Here is a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpYNLp?editors=001)

*In the demo, I didn,t chnage your teContainer object in case you need it like it is.